If $0<a_1,\ldots,a_n<1$ and $S_n = a_1+\ldots+a_n$ then show that $1-S_n<(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\cdots(1-a_n)<\frac{1}{1+S_n}$
If $0<a_1,\ldots,a_n<1$ and $S_n = a_1+\ldots+a_n$ then show that $$1-S_n<(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\cdots(1-a_n)<\frac{1}{1+S_n}.$$
I tried applying GM HM inequality taking $1-a_1$ and $1-a_2$ as $2$ terms and applied RMS AM inequality taking $1$ and $-a_1$ as $2$ terms, because I solved a similar question using AMGM inequality, but could not solve this one. Any hint would be helpful.
Edit : Can this be solved without Bernoulli's inequality? I have only started learning inequality,so I could not understand some of the answers below.

Context was clearly provided here. As usuals, the serial closers are at work today.

There are probably better solutions but induction works for the first inequality.
For the second, take reciprocals and compare $\frac{1}{1-a_i}$ and $1+a_i$.
I hope these hints help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_product_inequality

The lower bound is the generalized Bernoulli's inequality which can be proven by induction.
For the upper bound, we can likewise proceed by induction. If $L := (1+S_n) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-a_i) < 1$ then $(1+S_n+a_{n+1}) (1-a_{n+1})\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1-a_i)  = (1-a_{n+1})L + a_{n+1}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1-a_i)$ which is a weighted average of $L$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (1-a_i)$ hence $<1$.

Another link for the proof by induction of the lower bound: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1013705

For the second inequality, notice that $1$ is the arithmetic mean of $(1-a_1)$, $(1-a_2)$, $\dots$ , $(1-a_n)$, $(1+S_n)$.
The first one, as pointed out, is the generalized Bernoulli's inequality.

2nd inequality should have been $\le \frac{1}{1+S_n}$ right?

@Heizenberg think about when you get equality in AM-GM...

My first posting got a bad reaction.
Here is as a Wiki.
Here is another proof of the right-hand-side using a little calculus:

Recall that $1+x<e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.
If $0<x_j<1$, $1\leq j\leq n$, then $0<1-x_j<1$ and
$$(1-x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1-x_n)\leq e^{-\sum^n_{k=1}x_k}$$
On the other hand,
$$1+x_1+\ldots + x_n<(1+x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+x_n)\leq e^{\sum^n_{k=1}x_k}$$
Hence $$e^{-\sum^n_{k=1}x_k}\leq \frac{1}{1+\sum^n_{k=1}x_k}$$

This gives $$(1-x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1-x_n)\leq \frac{1}{1+\sum^n_{k=1}x_k}$$

To prove the $1 - S_n < (1 + a_1)\cdots (1 + a_n)$, show that $1 - (1-a_1)\cdots (1-a_n)$ same as $$a_1 + (1-a_1)a_2 + \cdots + (1-a_1)\cdots (1-a_{n-1})a_n$$(Think of a telescoping sum.) Using the condition on $a_i$ we see that this sum is smaller than $a_1 + \cdots + a_n$, or $S_n$.
The second inequality follows from the inequalities $1 - a_i < \frac{1}{1 + a_i}$ and $(1 + a_1) \cdots (1 + a_n) > 1 + a_1 + \cdots + a_n$.
