How to prove that a product with constraints is greater than or equal to 1/2?
I am working with the following expression:
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} x_j \right) \geq \frac{1}{2}, $$
where the variables $x_j$ satisfy the following conditions:

$x_j \in [0, 1]$ for all $j$,

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 1 $$ (the sum of the $x_j$ from $j=1$ to $n$ is 1).


I would like to know how to prove this inequality using a known mathematical inequality, such as the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality (AM-GM) or any other useful technique.
I've tried applying Jensen's inequality and other tools, but I haven't found a proof that works for all $i$
Thank you in advance!

How does $n$ and $i$ relate? Should the $i - 1$ be $n$, or vice-versa?

This is in sense a duplicate of this posting https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4955725/121671

For ease of notation, let $y_j = \frac{1}{2}x_j$.
And so $y_j \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = \frac{1}{2}$$
Now we want $$ \prod_{j=1}^{i-1} \left( 1 - y_j \right) \geq \frac{1}{2}, $$
Consider $y_1$ and $y_2$.
$$(1 - y_1)(1 - y_2) = (1 - y_1 - y_2 + y_1y_2) \ge 1 - (y_1 + y_2)$$
By induction, $$(1 - y_1)(1 - y_2)...(1-y_{i-1}) \ge 1 - (y_1 + y_2 ... +y_{i-1}) \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
